# Overwrite information from one node with information from another node another xsl transform

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<REQUEST_GROUP MISMOVersionID = "2.3.1" >
< REQUESTING_PARTY >
< PREFERRED_RESPONSE _VersionIdentifier="2.3.1" _Format="XML"/>
</REQUESTING_PARTY>
<SUBMITTING_PARTY _Name = "NETOX" />
< REQUEST LoginAccountPassword="00JfDA.S0rxs6" LoginAccountIdentifier="XXXXX" InternalAccountIdentifier="XXXXX" RequestDatetime="2017-04-17T07:51:23">
<REQUEST_DATA>
  <CREDIT_REQUEST MISMOVersionID = "2.3.1" RequestingPartyRequestedByName="1009" LenderCaseIdentifier="5010904">
    <CREDIT_REQUEST_DATA CreditRequestDateTime = "2017-04-17T07:51:23" CreditRequestType="Joint" CreditRepositoriesSelectedCount="0" CreditReportType="Merge" BorrowerID="BNUM2 BNUM1" CreditRequestID="CRQ1" CreditReportRequestActionType="Submit">
      <CREDIT_REPOSITORY_INCLUDED _TransUnionIndicator = "Y" _ExperianIndicator="Y" _EquifaxIndicator="Y"/>
    </CREDIT_REQUEST_DATA>
     <LOAN_APPLICATION>
       <BORROWER BorrowerID = "BNUM2" JointAssetLiabilityReportingType="NotJointly" JointAssetBorrowerID="BNUM1" _PrintPositionType="Borrower" SchoolingYears="18" _SSN="500222000" _LastName="Homeowner" _HomeTelephoneNumber="9185454545" _FirstName="Mary" _BirthDate="19850202" _AgeAtApplicationYears="32">
         <_RESIDENCE _PostalCode = "74133" BorrowerResidencyDurationYears="6" _State="OK" _City="Tulsa" _StreetAddress="3214 E 30th Pl" BorrowerResidencyType="Current"/>
       </BORROWER>
       <BORROWER BorrowerID = "BNUM1" JointAssetLiabilityReportingType="NotJointly" JointAssetBorrowerID="BNUM2" _PrintPositionType="CoBorrower" SchoolingYears="21" _SSN="999405000" _LastName="Homeowner" _HomeTelephoneNumber="9185874547" _FirstName="John" _BirthDate="19780202" _AgeAtApplicationYears="39" MaritalStatusType="Unmarried">
         <_RESIDENCE _PostalCode = "74136" BorrowerResidencyDurationYears="6" _State="OK" _City="Tulsa" _StreetAddress="6600 S Yale Avenue" BorrowerResidencyType="Current"/>
       </BORROWER>
    </LOAN_APPLICATION>
  </CREDIT_REQUEST>
</REQUEST_DATA>
</REQUEST>

<MAILING_ADDRESS _PostalCode = "74137" BorrowerResidencyDurationYears="6" _State="OK" _City="Tulsa" _StreetAddress="1234 Fake St" BorrowerResidencyType="Current" _Bnum="2"/>
<MAILING_ADDRESS _PostalCode = "74133" BorrowerResidencyDurationYears="6" _State="OK" _City="Tulsa" _StreetAddress="7777 S Memorial Drive" BorrowerResidencyType="Current" _Bnum="1"/>

</REQUEST_GROUP>
```

I need to the overwrite the information in the _RESIDENCE node with the MAILING_ADDRESS information for each borrower.  In the BORROWER Node there is BorrowerID which corresponds to _Bnum in Mailing_Address.  _RESIDENCE should still be the node; only the information should change.  Everything I've tried ends up with both borrowers having the same address information.

Comment: "*In the BORROWER Node there is BorrowerID which corresponds to _Bnum in Mailing_Address.*" I don't see that it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, given this XML (had to clean-up formatting a bit).

```
<REQUEST_GROUP MISMOVersionID = "2.3.1" >
<REQUESTING_PARTY >
<PREFERRED_RESPONSE _VersionIdentifier="2.3.1" _Format="XML"/>
</REQUESTING_PARTY>
<SUBMITTING_PARTY _Name = "NETOX" />
<REQUEST LoginAccountPassword="00JfDA.S0rxs6" LoginAccountIdentifier="XXXXX" InternalAccountIdentifier="XXXXX" RequestDatetime="2017-04-17T07:51:23">
<REQUEST_DATA>
  <CREDIT_REQUEST MISMOVersionID = "2.3.1" RequestingPartyRequestedByName="1009" LenderCaseIdentifier="5010904">
    <CREDIT_REQUEST_DATA CreditRequestDateTime = "2017-04-17T07:51:23" CreditRequestType="Joint" CreditRepositoriesSelectedCount="0" CreditReportType="Merge" BorrowerID="BNUM2 BNUM1" CreditRequestID="CRQ1" CreditReportRequestActionType="Submit">
      <CREDIT_REPOSITORY_INCLUDED _TransUnionIndicator = "Y" _ExperianIndicator="Y" _EquifaxIndicator="Y"/>
    </CREDIT_REQUEST_DATA>
     <LOAN_APPLICATION>
       <BORROWER BorrowerID = "BNUM2" JointAssetLiabilityReportingType="NotJointly" JointAssetBorrowerID="BNUM1" _PrintPositionType="Borrower" SchoolingYears="18" _SSN="500222000" _LastName="Homeowner" _HomeTelephoneNumber="9185454545" _FirstName="Mary" _BirthDate="19850202" _AgeAtApplicationYears="32">
         <_RESIDENCE _PostalCode = "74133" BorrowerResidencyDurationYears="6" _State="OK" _City="Tulsa" _StreetAddress="3214 E 30th Pl" BorrowerResidencyType="Current"/>
       </BORROWER>
       <BORROWER BorrowerID = "BNUM1" JointAssetLiabilityReportingType="NotJointly" JointAssetBorrowerID="BNUM2" _PrintPositionType="CoBorrower" SchoolingYears="21" _SSN="999405000" _LastName="Homeowner" _HomeTelephoneNumber="9185874547" _FirstName="John" _BirthDate="19780202" _AgeAtApplicationYears="39" MaritalStatusType="Unmarried">
         <_RESIDENCE _PostalCode = "74136" BorrowerResidencyDurationYears="6" _State="OK" _City="Tulsa" _StreetAddress="6600 S Yale Avenue" BorrowerResidencyType="Current"/>
       </BORROWER>
    </LOAN_APPLICATION>
  </CREDIT_REQUEST>
</REQUEST_DATA>
</REQUEST>

<MAILING_ADDRESS _PostalCode = "74137" BorrowerResidencyDurationYears="6" _State="OK" _City="Tulsa" _StreetAddress="1234 Fake St" BorrowerResidencyType="Current" _Bnum="2"/>
<MAILING_ADDRESS _PostalCode = "74133" BorrowerResidencyDurationYears="6" _State="OK" _City="Tulsa" _StreetAddress="7777 S Memorial Drive" BorrowerResidencyType="Current" _Bnum="1"/>

</REQUEST_GROUP>
```

This XSLT will produce the results.  The trick is to use an identity transform, grab the addresses you need and convert BNUM1 to @_Bnum='1'.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<!-- Store the addresses so we can get to them later-->
<xsl:variable name='mailing' select='//MAILING_ADDRESS'/>

<!-- A regular identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='BORROWER/_RESIDENCE'>
    <!-- Convert "BNUM1" to just 1 and store in $addressid-->
    <xsl:variable name='addressid' select='substring(ancestor::BORROWER/@BorrowerID, 5)'/>

    <!-- use the address id to find the MAILING_ADDRESS-->
    <xsl:variable name='address' select='$mailing[@_Bnum=$addressid]'/>

    <xsl:element name='_RESIDENCE'>
        <xsl:attribute name='addressid'><xsl:value-of select='$addressid'/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name='_PostalCode'><xsl:value-of select='$address/@_PostalCode'/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name='_State'><xsl:value-of select='$address/@_State'/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name='_City'><xsl:value-of select='$address/@_City'/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name='_StreetAddress'><xsl:value-of select='$address/@_StreetAddress'/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name='BorrowerResidencyDurationYears'><xsl:value-of select='$address/@BorrowerResidencyDurationYears'/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name='BorrowerResidencyType'><xsl:value-of select='$address/@BorrowerResidencyType'/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will produce this XML result

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<REQUEST_GROUP MISMOVersionID="2.3.1">
<REQUESTING_PARTY>
<PREFERRED_RESPONSE _VersionIdentifier="2.3.1" _Format="XML">
</PREFERRED_RESPONSE>
</REQUESTING_PARTY>
<SUBMITTING_PARTY _Name="NETOX">
</SUBMITTING_PARTY>
<REQUEST LoginAccountPassword="00JfDA.S0rxs6" LoginAccountIdentifier="XXXXX" InternalAccountIdentifier="XXXXX" RequestDatetime="2017-04-17T07:51:23">
<REQUEST_DATA>
<CREDIT_REQUEST MISMOVersionID="2.3.1" RequestingPartyRequestedByName="1009" LenderCaseIdentifier="5010904">
<CREDIT_REQUEST_DATA CreditRequestDateTime="2017-04-17T07:51:23" CreditRequestType="Joint" CreditRepositoriesSelectedCount="0" CreditReportType="Merge" BorrowerID="BNUM2 BNUM1" CreditRequestID="CRQ1" CreditReportRequestActionType="Submit">
<CREDIT_REPOSITORY_INCLUDED _TransUnionIndicator="Y" _ExperianIndicator="Y" _EquifaxIndicator="Y">
</CREDIT_REPOSITORY_INCLUDED>
</CREDIT_REQUEST_DATA>
<LOAN_APPLICATION>
<BORROWER BorrowerID="BNUM2" JointAssetLiabilityReportingType="NotJointly" JointAssetBorrowerID="BNUM1" _PrintPositionType="Borrower" SchoolingYears="18" _SSN="500222000" _LastName="Homeowner" _HomeTelephoneNumber="9185454545" _FirstName="Mary" _BirthDate="19850202" _AgeAtApplicationYears="32">
<_RESIDENCE addressid="2" _PostalCode="74137" _State="OK" _City="Tulsa" _StreetAddress="1234 Fake St" BorrowerResidencyDurationYears="6" BorrowerResidencyType="Current" />
</BORROWER>
<BORROWER BorrowerID="BNUM1" JointAssetLiabilityReportingType="NotJointly" JointAssetBorrowerID="BNUM2" _PrintPositionType="CoBorrower" SchoolingYears="21" _SSN="999405000" _LastName="Homeowner" _HomeTelephoneNumber="9185874547" _FirstName="John" _BirthDate="19780202" _AgeAtApplicationYears="39" MaritalStatusType="Unmarried">
<_RESIDENCE addressid="1" _PostalCode="74133" _State="OK" _City="Tulsa" _StreetAddress="7777 S Memorial Drive" BorrowerResidencyDurationYears="6" BorrowerResidencyType="Current" />
</BORROWER>
</LOAN_APPLICATION>
</CREDIT_REQUEST>
</REQUEST_DATA>
</REQUEST>
<MAILING_ADDRESS _PostalCode="74137" BorrowerResidencyDurationYears="6" _State="OK" _City="Tulsa" _StreetAddress="1234 Fake St" BorrowerResidencyType="Current" _Bnum="2">
</MAILING_ADDRESS>
<MAILING_ADDRESS _PostalCode="74133" BorrowerResidencyDurationYears="6" _State="OK" _City="Tulsa" _StreetAddress="7777 S Memorial Drive" BorrowerResidencyType="Current" _Bnum="1">
</MAILING_ADDRESS>
</REQUEST_GROUP>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the identity transformation with an override for `_RESIDENCE` that will copy over the attributes from the corresponding `MAILING_ADDRESS` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="_RESIDENCE">
    <xsl:variable name="residenceBnum"
                  select="substring(../@BorrowerID, 5)"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="/REQUEST_GROUP
                           /MAILING_ADDRESS[@_Bnum = $residenceBnum]/@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You may want to apply additional filters to the attributes if there are some you wish to omit from the new `_RESIDENCE` element.  (You didn't specify, for example, if `@_Bnum` should come over.)